# Parsing XML with keys that have spaces in their names

Tags: php, parsing, simplexml

Does anyone know how to parse an xml string in php using SimpleXMLElement when the key has a space in it ?

For example,

```
$xmlString = "<test><this is>a</this is></test>";
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
print_r($xml);
```

in the above example, 'this is' causes the parser to go bananas. I'm guessing its because it thinks its a property as is expecting like   ??

FOR A BONUS PT,
 (also if the key is a number.. like '1', the same thing happens)..

Comment: Actually the parser thinks `is` is an attribute, as indicated by the parser error message `Entity: line 1: parser error : Specification mandate value for attribute is`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because having numbers as elements and elements with spaces is not part of valid XML.  You're probably better off running a replacement function on your XML string, converting `<(\d+)>` to `<el_$1>`, and replacing spaces in nodes with underscores as well.